# Cross-Over with string Encoded Chromosomes

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, genetic-algorithm, mutation, crossover

I am implementing Genetic Algorithm (GA).
There are `43` numbers [Ambulance Locations] to choose from `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)` , I choose `3` places since I have `3` ambulances.

I can only put my ambulance in `3` locations among `1-39 locations` **(Restriction)**.

A chromosome sample: `[000010000000000000100000000000100000000]`. This represents that I want to put my Ambulance on the `5th, 19th, and 31 positions.` The bits against positions `5th`, `19th`, and `31` are `1` and rest positions are `0`. In other words, I am turning on `5-bit, 19-bit, and 31-bit`.

Let's say

```
Candidate solution 1 (111000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

and

```
Candidate Solution 2 (000000000000000000000000000000000000111)
```

My candidate solutions are encoded in 39-bits,I want to do a cross-over these 39-bits.
Above two candidates solutions are a bit weird.
What can be done here?

**What can be a good approach to perform cross-over while puting ambulances in `3` locations among `1-39 locations`?**

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "crossover".  Do you mean reversing the bits?  You can reverse a string in Python by doing `s[::-1]`.  If you just want to put the bits in the opposite order, then instead of adding `1 << i`, add in `1 << (31-i)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am using the genetic algorithm to perform cross-over. I need to create off-spring/child from parents chromosomes.

Comment: @AdilAbid So how exactly is this related to ambulances?

Comment: @pigrammer I need to explore my search space. My Search Space is `9139`. Following the genetic algorithm, I need to perform mutation and cross-over to find the best 3 locations to put my ambulances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPs question**

There are many ways to perform crossover - in this example as we must end up with the same number of bits in the input and the output I have used a crossover between the bits, allowing for 0-3 bits to get swapped between the two inputs.

The solution provided is dynamic and will work for any length chromosome with any number of flipped bits (1s).

```py
import random
from typing import Union
def crossover(cs1: str, cs2: str) -> Union[str, str]:
    if len(cs1) != len(cs2):
        raise Exception("Candidate solutions input are of different length.")
    # get the flipped bits in each string
    cs1_bits = [index for index, gene in enumerate(cs1) if gene == "1"]
    cs2_bits = [index for index, gene in enumerate(cs2) if gene == "1"]
    if len(cs1_bits) != len(cs2_bits):
        raise Exception("Candidate solutions input have different number of flipped bits.")
    index: int = random.randint(0, len(cs1_bits))
    sol1_bits, sol2_bits = cs1_bits[:index] + cs2_bits[index:], cs2_bits[:index] + cs1_bits[index:]
    output_1 = ""
    output_2 = ""
    for i in range(len(cs1)):
        if i in sol1_bits:
            output_1 += "1"
        else:
            output_1 += "0"
        if i in sol2_bits:
            output_2 += "1"
        else:
            output_2 += "0"
    return output_1, output_2
```

Example input/output for OPs solution.

```py
# Input
"111000000000000000000000000000000000000", "000000000000000000000000000000000000111"
# Output
'110000000000000000000000000000000000001', '001000000000000000000000000000000000110'
```

---

**How to perform standard crossover**

You perform crossover in a genetic algorithm by selecting a random index along the length of the number of values, in your instance, you will choose a value between 0-38 (39 options).

You will then split both of the inputs and join the front of `cs1` onto the back of `cs2` and vice versa.

```py
from typing import Union
import random
def crossover(cs1: str, cs2: str) -> Union[str, str]:
    index: int = random.randint(0, len(cs1))
    return cs1[:index] + cs2[index:], cs2[:index] + cs1[index:]
```

If you have the values:

```py
cs1 = "111000000000000000000000000000000000000"
cs2 = "000000000000000000000000000000000000111"
```

Crossing over with an index of 1 will return:

```py
output_1 = "100000000000000000000000000000000000111"
output_2 = "011000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Crossing over with an index of 5 will return:

```py
output_1 = "111000000000000000000000000000000000111"
output_2 = "000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: Can you also suggest me how to 'mutate` `cs1 = "111000000000000000000000000000000000000"` in a good and organized way? Just like cross-over?

Comment: Ask another question, reply to me here when you have done so and I will answer it for you.

Comment: I have posted another question for mutation. Please have a look. This is my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73966258/mutation-with-string-encoded-chromosomes-genetic-algorithm)

Comment: I have question. If we look at the `output_1` = `"111000000000000000000000000000000000111"`, I am getting `six` `1's`. However, it is a must for me to only keep `3bits` (only 3 ambulances) after a cross-over. What should I do?

Comment: @JeremySavage I think unform-crossover can solve such problems. This solution will mostly result in illegal offspring.

Comment: I have updated to return only 3 bits - sorry I did not read your question correctly. I have left the original solution below as it may be useful for someone else.

Comment: @JeremySavage Your solution code is based on a `One Point Crossover`, `Multi-Point Crossover`, or `Uniform Crossover`?

Comment: The solution is a variation of a `one-point` crossover. An `index` is chosen and then bits on either side of the index are swapped over. As you have only 3 possible solutions selected at a time I think `one-point` makes sense. You could also use a `uniform crossover` to solve this, but a `multi-point crossover` would not make sense due to the lack of solutions available.